# Como criar lista encadeada simples circular em C ?

Tags: c

OBS: O primeiro elemento estou inserindo fora da qui, isso aqui é pro segundo em diante, o while vai rodar até o usuário digitar o id de um aluno -1 q ta na função criar. Está caindo em loop infinito!

```
void inserir(Aluno *aluno){

while(1){
    if(aluno->prox == NULL){
        Aluno *aux = aluno;
        Aluno *novo = criar();
        if(novo->id < 0)
            break;
        aux->prox = novo;
        novo->prox = aux;
    }else{

        Aluno *aux = aluno->prox;
        while(aux->prox != aluno){ // entra e um loop infinito
            printf("3\n");
            aux = aux->prox;

        }
        Aluno *novo = criar();
            if(novo->id < 0)
                break;  
            aux->prox=novo;
            novo->prox=aux; 
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lista circular simples é definida por ao invés do próximo do ultimo aportar para nulo, aponta para o primeiro da lista.

```
       Aluno *novo = criar();
        if(novo->id < 0)
            break;  
        aux->prox=novo;
        novo->prox=aux;
```

Você está criando um novo nó, fazendo ele apontar para o anterior dele. Nenhum nó ira apontar para aluno.

```
    Aluno *novo = criar();
        if(novo->id < 0)
            break;  
        aux->prox=novo;
        novo->prox=aluno;
```

Agora sim, aponta para aluno e não vai cair em loop.

Comment: muito obrigado, ajudou bastante